# Selenium not able to load the given URL instead loading the main page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/site/promo/health-fitness-deals")

tag = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h4')
for a in tag:
    for link in a.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
        print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Main Page that is being loaded by the website :
[image]

The page that I want to scrape :
https://www.bestbuy.com/site/promo/health-fitness-deals

Comment: what location you want to choose ?

Comment: Can you `.click()` through the element on the appropriate country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this link instead `https://www.bestbuy.com/site/promo/health-fitness-deals?intl=nosplash` so basically you'll add `intl=nosplash` to the link